# AEM CQ5 Design dialog content not available in publish instance

Tags: aem

After testing some setting on our design dialogs we noticed that the data is not being carried over and picked up by our components on the publish instance. Our components work great on design and preview view but once they go to the publish instance all the settings are lost. Any ideas why this may occur?

Comment: what settings are you talking about? Usually stuff in the Design Dialog is only relevant for editing and thus it would make sense, that you don't see it on publishing...

Comment: Hi Thomas, a basic example is that we extended the title component and added the functionality to change the header tag at the design level. This works great on design/preview but doesn't make it through to publish. It does make sense when you mention that this is only relevant for editing tho...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the limited information available in the question, I guess, the design configuration is not moved to publish environment along with the content.

In case you have configured the design path in the page properties, either in the current page or any of its parent page, make sure that the corresponding design is also replicated to the Publish environment.

In case the design path is not configured in any of the pages, by default your design configuration gets stored under `/etc/designs/default` (which is not recommended).

If the above is the issue, you can use either of the following methods to fix it.

1. Create a new design page under `/etc/designs`, and configure the path of that design in the parent / root page of your site. This would ensure that all the pages would use the same design to save the design level configuration. After this, replicate that design to your publish instance.
2. Another approach which might provide a quick fix but not recommended at any level is to replicate the `/etc/designs/default` to your publish and check if the content pages are now picking up the correct values.

Comment: Thanks @rakhi4110, our design was not being replicated to the Publish environment.